# Is there a word for "not self-righteous"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "not self-righteous"?  Humble doesn't quite fit, but someone who does what they need to but is not self-righteous in their demeanor or actions.

Comment: The opposite of 'unrighteous' is 'righteous'. The opposite of 'self-righteous' is 'justified', that is to say 'justified by another' (rather than self).

Comment: @NigelJ  I really don't think that 'self-rigetheous' is the opposite of 'justified' and righteuous definition includes justified.   I believe that the use of "self" brings in concepts of smugness and intolerance which is more about demeanor than altering whether their stance is justified or not.   Self righteousness might be described as -Ungracious display of  justification- IMO . I wrote up **gracious** as an answer but deleted as it does not stand alone for the full meaning.

Comment: reference for the 'smug and intolerant aspect of self righteous http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-righteous?s=t  and  for the meaning justified for righteous http://www.dictionary.com/browse/righteous

Comment: @Tom22 'Self-righteous' is being right in one's own estimation. 'Justified' is being right in the estimation of another, that is to say being deemed 'righteous' in the eyes of another. It is a matter of rightness or, 'righteousness' or, as The Wycliffe has it in Old English - 'rightwiseness'.

Answer (score 1):

**unpretentious**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unpretentious)

> 1. Lacking pretension or affectation; modest: a talented but unpretentious musician; an unpretentious speech accepting the award.
> 2. Not elaborate, ornate, or ostentatious

Comment: How about "un-self-righteous".  Possible, but probably not the best choice.  "Unpretentious" is a good choice.